# Swiftでホスト名やIPアドレス、MACアドレスを取得する

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

コマンドラインでのarp -aのように同じLANに存在する通信デバイスのホスト名やIPアドレス、MACアドレスをXcodeでSwiftを使用しMacOSX用ソフトウェアを作り取得したいと考えています。
どのような方法が考えられますでしょうか。
ご教授頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: CFHostGetAddressingでIPアドレスの取得は可能とのことがでているのですが、ホスト自体が不明な場合はどのようにすべきでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

arp-scanのソースを見て参考にすればいいんじゃないでしょうか。
この辺とか。
https://github.com/royhills/arp-scan

Answer (score 0):

IPアドレスとMACアドレスの対応付けには、ARPというプロトコルを使います。
MACアドレスは各マシンの通信ボードが半永久的に保持していますが、IPアドレスは変更されることがあります。（昔は通信ボードのMACアドレスはハードウェアで固定されていましたが、最近はソフトウェアで書き換えられるようになっている通信ボードがあります）

IPアドレスとホスト名の対応付けは、各マシンが持つhostsファイルによるものと、DNSによるものがあります。

なので、ARP、hosts、DNSの３つに関する仕組みを知っていて、これらを使いこなせればプログラムを作ることができるはずです。